# Sub-classing the user model from models.Model directly instead of using custom user models in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Everywhere, everyone seems to be using "custom user model" derived from either `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser` class.

Why nobody directly sub-classes the user model from `models.Model`?
Won't that be much easier and simpler?

What additional functionality does using these custom user models provide?

Answer (score 0):

As the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) state:

> The easiest way to construct a compliant custom user model is to inherit from AbstractBaseUser. AbstractBaseUser provides the core implementation of a user model, **including hashed passwords and tokenized password resets.** You must then provide some key implementation details.

The `AbstractBaseUser` doesnt come with fields apart from `password`, `last_login` and `is_active`. You use `AbstractBaseUser` when you want to implement a custom user and use different fields and/or authentication than the ones `AbstractUser` comes with.

`AbstractUser` subclasses `AbstractBaseUser` and provides a base implementation of an User model. With `AbstractUser` you basically use the `User` model with all its fields, but it comes with extra inherited functions and Django's implementation of authentication. You use `AbstractUser` when you are happy with the way Django provides an User and handles authentication.